# GoogleApis: Unable to authenticate using service account json file

Tags: node.js, google-api

I am trying to authenticate a Node.js app (that will eventually be part of an Express.js backend) for the gmail api. In my .env file I have set the absolute path to the credentials.json file under Env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

I then try to run a simple function to print a list of messages

```
async function runSample() {
  <message setup removed>

  try {
    const res = await gmail.users.messages.send({
      userId: 'me',
      requestBody: {
        raw: encodedMessage,
      },
    });

    console.log(res.data);
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}

runSample();

// (node:15522) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
// Error: Error: Login Required.
```

I thought this authentication flow did not require explicit scope grants or login. If that is incorrect, what changes need to be made to handle login?

Answer (score 0):

According to official [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs), you need to authorize through oAuth2, also specifiy scopes

```
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];

const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';


fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), runSample);  // this is important
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}


async function runSample(auth) {


  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});


  try {
    const res = await gmail.users.messages.send({
      userId: 'me',
      requestBody: {
        raw: encodedMessage,
      },
    });

    console.log(res.data);
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```